# openxml or closedxml work with xlsb file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, export-to-excel, closedxml

I am unable to write data to Excel binary ".xlsb" file using openxml with c#

i want to use it for writing data to binary "xlsb" file using c# but without excel interpro.

i tried openxml but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Open XML SDK cannot handle .xlsb files since they are stored as binary. The Office XML Formats which Open XML SDK could recognize are based on XML and ZIP technologies, rather than binary. Generally Open XML SDK could handle spreadsheets like ".xlsx", "xlsm", "xltx" and so on.

i found it in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bf78ca1d-50dd-4690-8bc6-fbcdecacddb3/handle-xlsb-files?forum=oxmlsdk